# Kudu Client fails with exceptions after running for few days

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, apache-kudu

I have a Scala/Spark/Kafka process that I run. When I first start the process I create a KuduClient Object using a function I made that I share between classes. For this job I only create the KuduClient once, and let the process run continuously. I've noticed that after several days I frequently get exceptions.

I'm not really sure what to do. I think maybe an option would be to create a new Kudu client every day or so but I'm unsure of how to do that in this case as well.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.json.JSONObject
import org.apache.kudu.client.KuduClient
import org.apache.log4j.Logger

object Thing extends Serializable {

  @transient lazy val client: KuduClient = createKuduClient(config)
  @transient lazy val logger: Logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    UtilFunctions.loadConfig(args) //I send back a config object.
    UtilFunctions.loadLogger() //factory method to load logger

    val props: Map[String, String] = setKafkaProperties()

    val topic = Set(config.getString("config.TOPIC_NAME"))

    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName(config.getString("config.SPARK_APP_NAME"))
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))
    ssc.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    ssc.checkpoint(config.getString("config.SPARK_CHECKPOINT_NAME"))

    // val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, props, topic)
    val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topic, props))
    val distRecordsStream = kafkaStream.map(record => (record.key(), record.value()))
    distRecordsStream.window(Seconds(10), Seconds(10))
    distRecordsStream.foreachRDD(distRecords => {
      logger.info(distRecords + " : " + distRecords.count())
      distRecords.foreach(record => {
        logger.info(record._2)
        MyClass.DoSomethingWithThisData(new JSONObject(record._2), client)
      })
    })

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

  def createKuduClient(config: Config): KuduClient = {
    var client: KuduClient = null
    try{
      client = new KuduClient.KuduClientBuilder(config.getString("config.KUDU_MASTER"))
        .defaultAdminOperationTimeoutMs(config.getInt("config.KUDU_ADMIN_TIMEOUT_S") * 1000)
        .defaultOperationTimeoutMs(config.getInt("config.KUDU_OPERATION_TIMEOUT_S") * 1000)
        .build()
    }
    catch {
      case e: Throwable =>
        logger.error(e.getMessage)
        logger.error(e.getStackTrace.toString)
        Thread.sleep(10000) //try to create a new kudu client
        client = createKuduClient(config)
    }
    client //return
  }

  def setKafkaProperties(): Map[String, String] = {


    val zookeeper = config.getString("config.ZOOKEEPER")
    val offsetReset = config.getString("config.OFFSET_RESET")
    val brokers = config.getString("config.BROKERS")
    val groupID = config.getString("config.GROUP_ID")
    val deserializer = config.getString("config.DESERIALIZER")
    val autoCommit = config.getString("config.AUTO_COMMIT")
    val maxPollRecords = config.getString("config.MAX_POLL_RECORDS")
    val maxPollIntervalms = config.getString("config.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS")

    val props = Map(
      "bootstrap.servers" -> brokers,
      "zookeeper.connect" -> zookeeper,
      "group.id" -> groupID,
      "key.deserializer" -> deserializer,
      "value.deserializer" -> deserializer,
      "enable.auto.commit" -> autoCommit,
      "auto.offset.reset" -> offsetReset,
      "max.poll.records" -> maxPollRecords,
      "max.poll.interval.ms" -> maxPollIntervalms)
    props
  }

}
```

Exceptions below. I've removed the IP address inplace of using "x"

> ERROR client.TabletClient: [Peer
>   master-ip-xxx-xx-xxx-40.ec2.internal:7051] Unexpected exception from
>   downstream on [id: 0x42ba3f4d, /xxx.xx.xxx.39:36820 =>
>   ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-40.ec2.internal/xxx.xx.xxx.40:7051]
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize the response,
>   incompatible RPC? Error is: step
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.KuduRpc.readProtobuf(KuduRpc.java:383)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.Negotiator.parseSaslMsgResponse(Negotiator.java:282)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.Negotiator.handleResponse(Negotiator.java:235)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.Negotiator.messageReceived(Negotiator.java:229)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.messageReceived(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:184)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:70)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:310)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
>           at org.apache.kudu.client.shaded.org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I've also seen exceptions like these after running for a while which [others](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/147083/all-datanodes-are-bad.html) seem to attribute to being the open file handles limit of your user.

> java.io.IOException: All datanodes
>   DatanodeInfoWithStorage[xxx.xx.xxx.36:1004,DS-55c403c3-203a-4dac-b383-72fcdb686185,DISK]
>   are bad. Aborting...
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.setupPipelineForAppendOrRecovery(DFSOutputStream.java:1465)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.processDatanodeError(DFSOutputStream.java:1236)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputSt

Is this have something too do with having too many open files? A way to "purge" these files once they reach a limit?